# Shortcode displaying WooCommerce current product categories or tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, taxonomy-terms

I would like to make a two shortcodes for displaying Woocommerce product.

Shortcode 1:

- Display Woocommerce CURRENT product tags.
- The tags has to be links.
- The tags has to seperated by ,

Shortcode 2:

- Display Woocommerce CURRENT pruduct category
- The tags has to be links.
- The tags has to seperated by ,

The short codes should display the category / links just like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgRsQ.png)

I have tried this shortcode, but the displayed tags are not links.
I would like to have them displayed as links.

```
add_shortcode( 'wc_product_tag', 'get_tag_term_name_for_product_id' );
function get_tag_term_name_for_product_id( $atts ) {
    // Shortcode attribute (or argument)
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_tag', // The WooCommerce "product tag" taxonomy (as default)
        'product_id' => get_the_id(), // The current product Id (as default)
    ), $atts, 'wc_product_tag' ) );
    
    $term_names = (array) wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'names') );
 
    if( ! empty($term_names) ){
        // return a term name or multiple term names (in a coma separated string)
        return implode(', ', $term_names);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following shortcode to get linked terms:

```php
add_shortcode( 'wc_product_cat', 'get_custom_post_linked_term_names' );
function get_custom_post_linked_term_names( $atts ) {
    // Shortcode attribute (or argument)
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat', // Product categories as default (Use 'product_tag' for product tags)
        'product_id' => get_the_id(), // current default product Iddefault)
    ), $atts, 'wc_product_cat' ) );
    
    $terms = (array) wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy );
    $linked_terms = array(); // Initializing
 
    if( empty($terms) ) return; // Exit
    
    // Loop through each term
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link($term); // get term link
        $linked_terms[] = $term_link ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $term_link, $term->name ) : $term->name;
    }

    return implode(', ', $linked_terms);
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

**USAGE**

1. For product categories: `[wc_product_cat]`
2. For product tags: `[wc_product_cat taxonomy="product_tag"]`
3. For other taxonomies define the taxonomy using the taxonomy shortcode argument